# Angular if/else defaulting to else because of async dependancy

Tags: angular, typescript, http, routes

I have a component that has 2 child routes and loads the corresponding components below itself. If you click one route, it replaces the other one that was previously loaded. Currently, both child components get their information via an observable/service/network call. On both of their HTML pages, there is an if/else statement. If the variable(array) exists and isn't empty load `if`, else load `else`. My problem is that whenever I go to a child component, it defaults to the `else` statement because of the async nature of how they get their information. This causes a flicker where you can see the contents of the `else` block before the `if` block replaces it when valid. What I want is to load `else` only if the array remains empty after the service is consumed.

Comment: I recommend using resolve so the data will be there when that component is loaded. Hope this helps.

Comment: Or you can simply use a different value (null, undefined) or a separae flag (boolean loaded) to avoid displaying anything while the data isn't loaded yet.